# Why do we recite Targum translation for 3 verses in "Kedusha Desidra"?

Tags: tefilla, targumin

Following Shacharit Shemonah Esreh, during Shabbat Mincha, and after the Amidah on Motza'ei Shabbat, קדושה דסדרא also called, ובא לציון is said. The beginning contains 3 verses, 2 of which are part of *Kedusha* that is recited as part of the chazzan's Amidah repetition, and the third from Shemot (Exodus) 15:

> וְקָרָא זֶה אֶל זֶה וְאָמַר קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ | קָדוֹשׁ יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת
>   מְלֹא כָל הָאָרֶץ כְּבוֹדוֹ:
>   וּמְקַבְּלִין דֵין מִן דֵין וְאָמְרִין קַדִּישׁ בִּשְמֵי מֵרוֹמַא
>   עִלָאַה בֵּית שְכִינְתֵּהּ, קַדִּישׁ עַל אַרְעָא עוֹבַד גְּבוּרְתֵּהּ,
>   קַדִּישׁ לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא, יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת מַלְיָא כָּל
>   אַרְעָא זִיו יְקָרֵהּ: וַתִּשָּׂאֵנִי רוּחַ וָאֶשְׁמַע אַחֲרַי קוֹל
>   רַעַשׁ גָּדוֹל **בָּרוּךְ** כְּבוֹד יְהֹוָה מִמְּקוֹמוֹ:
>   וּנְטָלַתְנִי רוּחָא וּשְׁמָעִית בַּתְרַי קַל זִיעַ שַׂגִּיא
>   דִמְשַׁבְּחִין וְאָמְרִין, בְּרִיךְ יְקָרָא דְיְהֹוָה מֵאֲתָר בֵּית
>   שְכִינְתֵּהּ, **יְהֹוָה** יִמְלוֹךְ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד, יְהֹוָה
>   מַלְכוּתֵיהּ קָאִים לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא

Why are these 3 verses recited with the Aramaic Targum Yonatan translation? None of the other verses are translated. What is the functional purpose of doing this as part of the *tefillah*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbi Eliyahu Munk, in his book עולם התפילות, gives several reasons for this (which we say every day, not only on Shabbat):

- This is the end of the *teffilah*, after we already reached the hights during *Shma Yisrael* and *Amida*, and we are slowly descending and equipping ourselves towards our day. Therefore we need the explanation of the *targum* for example that states that "קדוש קדוש קדוש" doesn't just mean that Hashem is holy and far away from us, but he is "קדיש על ארעא" - holy down on earth as well.
- The Abudraham explains that this *kedushah* is here for those who came late to prayer, and missed the regular *kedushah* of *amida*. They added the Aramaic translation because in that time that was the spoken language.
- Rav Natrunai also explains that Aramaic was the spoken language, but that they put this *kedushah* and its translations there as part of a *limud* of *psukim* and Mishna etc. that were done towards the end of the prayer. After some time, the rest was gone, but this part stayed on.
- Rashi on Sota 49a also gives the same explanation:

  > סדר קדושה שלא תקנוה אלא שיהו כל ישראל עוסקין בתורה בכל יום דבר מועט שאומר קריאתו ותרגומו והן כעוסקין בתורה...‏
- Once, our enemies forbade us from saying *kedushah*, and they even posted guards during prayer hours to make sure no one does. So the Jews postponed the *kedushah* to the end of *teffilah*, when the guards left, and added the Aramaic translation so that it is like two different *kedushot* replacing the two that were missed. During Shabbat, they could say *kedushah* in *Mussaf*, so it doesn't appear in the morning prayer.