# What is ‘kedusha desidra’?

Tags: tefilla, words

I sometimes see the *kedusha* of *uva letzion* referred to as *kedusha desidra* (e.g. in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 132:2).

What is the origin of this phrase? What does it mean?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68035/why-do-we-recite-targum-translation-for-3-verses-in-kedusha-desidra?r=SearchResults

Comment: [Sotah 49](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.49a.8) refers to it as such. You're looking for an earlier source or an explanation for where Chazal came up with this term.

Comment: @robev Sotah works great as a source. Thanks. Would also like to understand what Chazal meant by the term

Comment: See section 5 https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~ofery/papers/sidre_neviim.pdf (and worth rereading https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92225/759)

Comment: Thanks @DoubleAA looks fascinating...